# key frame required first error in webrtc android application. How to reduce framerate on incoming video?

Tags: android, webrtc, libjingle

We have a webrtc android application working properly, we are using Kurento as media server and it's sending video at 24 fps; however, the incoming video stream in the android app presents a sort of periodic lag, as if the first 15 frames of a second were processed and played smoothly but then the following 15 were skipped, so we end up with a video that plays smoothly for a few milliseconds but then pauses for a few milliseconds too.

I guess the incoming video framerate is too large for the android device to process so it skips some of the frames and then continues when the buffer is free again. I'm getting the following output in the logcat (which I've googled but found no answer to my problem) saying **key frame required first**:

```
12-28 20:12:27.857 19648-19769/mx.blacklabs.parallax E/org.webrtc.Logging: HardwareVideoDecoder: decode() - key frame required first
12-28 20:12:27.858 19648-19796/mx.blacklabs.parallax E/org.webrtc.Logging: HardwareVideoDecoder: decode() - key frame required first
12-28 20:12:27.858 19648-19769/mx.blacklabs.parallax E/org.webrtc.Logging: HardwareVideoDecoder: decode() - key frame required first
```

I get that same error message in chunks with milliseconds of difference so it looks like it is related to my problem.

**What I've tried**

-Using `maxFrameRate` `MediaConstraint` as shown [here](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=org.webrtc.MediaConstraints) but that seemed to have no effect. Besides, that seems to be intended for the localMediaStream while we're trying to decrease the remoteMediaStream instead.

**Observations**

The android device we're using is Moverio BT-300 which runs on android 5.1.1. I'm using the following webrtc implementation `org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.22672`

Comment: This appears to be a network issue. The error indicated means it has attempted to decode a P or B frame without the corresponding I frame. In order to stream MPEG2 video, you must have a low latency connection with bandwidth greater than 3 Mbps per client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Constraints reduce the frameRate on the video *source*, i.e. the *outgoing* frame rate. To reduce the incoming frame rate, have the other side reduce the outgoing frame rate, e.g. by telling it to via out-of-band signaling (if you control both ends).

Comment: Your answer is technically correct so I'll accept it. You're right, we control both ends so the logical thing to do is to reduce the outgoing frame rate.